# Getting error on angularJs unit testing using Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

i'm trying to perform a unit test with Karma and Jasmine but i get error ,, looking at my code and result can u help me fixing this issue please? I'm too new to this so the solution could be too simple..Thank you.

My Karma configuration:

```
        // Karma configuration

            module.exports = function(config) {
              config.set({

                // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
                basePath: '../',

                // frameworks to use
                // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
                frameworks: ['jasmine'],

                // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
                files: [
                  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
                  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
                  'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
                  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
                  'app/scripts/*.js',
                  'test/unit/**/*.js'
                ],

                // list of files to exclude
                exclude: [
                'test/protractor.conf.js', 'test/e2e/*.js'
                ],
                    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
                // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
                preprocessors: {
                },

                // test results reporter to use
                // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
                // available reporters:  https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
                reporters: ['progress'],

                // web server port
                port: 9876,

                // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
                colors: true,

                // level of logging
                // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
                logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

                // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
                autoWatch: true,
                    // start these browsers
                // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
                 browsers: ['Chrome','PhantomJS', 'PhantomJS_custom'],

                // you can define custom flags
                customLaunchers: {
                  'PhantomJS_custom': {
                    base: 'PhantomJS',
                    options: {
                      windowName: 'my-window',
                      settings: {
                        webSecurityEnabled: false
                      },
                    },
                    flags: ['--load-images=true'],
                    debug: true
                  }
                },

                phantomjsLauncher: {
                  // Have phantomjs exit if a ResourceError is encountered (useful if karma exits without killing phantom)
                  exitOnResourceError: true
                },

                // Continuous Integration mode
                // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
                singleRun: false,

                // Concurrency level
                // how many browser should be started simultaneous
                concurrency: Infinity
                })
            }
```

My controller:

```
            describe('Controller: MenuController', function () {

              // load the controller's module
              beforeEach(module('confusionApp'));

              var MenuController, scope, $httpBackend;
                //  Initialize  the controller  and a   mock    scope       
                beforeEach(inject(function  ($controller, _$httpBackend_,   $rootScope, menuFactory){
                //  place   here    mocked  dependencies                        
                    $httpBackend =  _$httpBackend_;                     
                    $httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:3000/dishes").respond([
                    {
                  "id": 0,
                  "name": "Uthapizza",
                  "image": "images/uthapizza.png",
                  "category": "mains",
                  "label": "Hot",
                  "price": "4.99",
                  "description": "A",
                  "comments":[{}]
                  },
                  {
                  "id": 1,
                  "name": "Zucchipakoda",
                  "image": "images/zucchipakoda.png",
                  "category": "mains",
                  "label": "New",
                  "price": "4.99",
                  "description": "A",
                  "comments":[{}]
                  }
                  ]);
                    scope   =   $rootScope.$new();
                    MenuController =    $controller('MenuController',   {                       
                    $scope: scope,  menuFactory:    menuFactory });
                    $httpBackend.flush();   

                     it('should have showDetails as false', function () {

                expect(scope.showDetails).toBeFalsy();

              });

              it('should create "dishes" with 2 dishes fetched from xhr', function(){

                  expect(scope.showMenu).toBeTruthy();
                  expect(scope.dishes).toBeDefined();
                  expect(scope.dishes.length).toBe(2);

              });

              it('should have the correct data order in the dishes', function() {

                  expect(scope.dishes[0].name).toBe("Uthapizza");
                  expect(scope.dishes[1].label).toBe("New");

              });

              it('should change the tab selected based on tab clicked', function(){

                  expect(scope.tab).toEqual(1);

                  scope.select(3);

                  expect(scope.tab).toEqual(3);
                  expect(scope.filtText).toEqual('mains');

                    });
                }));

            });
```

This is what is on Chrome

```
           Karma v1.1.1 - connected
           Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0) is idle
           PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) is idle
           PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) is idle
           Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0) is idle
```

And this is Terminal report:

```
                PS D:\programming\web\angular.js\gulp\conFusion\test>      karma start karma.conf.js
            16 07 2016 17:49:04.773:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
            16 07 2016 17:49:04.820:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.1.1 server started at http://localhost:9876/
            16 07 2016 17:49:04.835:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome, PhantomJS, PhantomJS_custom with unlimited concurrency
            16 07 2016 17:49:05.007:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
            16 07 2016 17:49:05.054:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
            16 07 2016 17:49:19.550:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
            16 07 2016 17:49:19.561:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: ACTION REQUIRED:
            16 07 2016 17:49:19.562:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]:
            16 07 2016 17:49:19.564:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]:   Launch browser at
            16 07 2016 17:49:19.571:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]:   http://localhost:9000/webkit/inspector/inspector.html?page=2
            16 07 2016 17:49:19.575:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]:
            16 07 2016 17:49:19.579:INFO [phantomjs.launcher]: Waiting 15 seconds ...
            16 07 2016 17:49:21.051:INFO [Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#YCvvpIyKkfV8Zt7uAAAA with id 31119843
            16 07 2016 17:49:21.728:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#1j0xHL_FNxuWzb3TAAAB with id 96164824
            16 07 2016 17:49:36.243:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#9xpNc4LhgBzDKWEfAAAC with id 44407334
            PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.005 secs / 0 secs)
            PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.005 secs / 0 secs)
            Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.039 secs / 0 secs)
            16 07 2016 17:50:18.653:INFO [Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#_CyPLIKTHNnT1d0HAAAD with id manual-8566
            PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.004 secs / 0 secs)
            PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.008 secs / 0 secs)
            Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.007 secs / 0 secs)
            Chrome 51.0.2704 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.012 secs / 0 secs)
```

Update: i moved the tests outside inject, but it seems i got errors in my project .. 
but still also can see errors related to testing itself.. 
here is what i get :

[image: here is the screenshot]

what about these errors , are they related to the testing code or just showing the result of my test?

```
    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (4 FAILED) ERROR (0.038 secs / 0.055 secs)
    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (4 FAILED) ERROR (0.047 secs / 0
    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (4 FAILED) ERROR (0.038 secs / 0.055 secs)
    PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (4 FAILED) ERROR (0.047 secs / 0.059 secs)
    Chrome 52.0.2743 (Windows 10 0.0.0): Executed 4 of 4 (4 FAILED) ERROR (0.117 secs / 0.057 secs)
```

Comment: and where is the Error? I think your terminal output is not complete

Comment: please look at last 4 lines, there is an error on each line

Comment: I got it, check the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have included your modular tests inside the inject function, so you should re-write the code as´:

```
beforeEach(inject(function  ($controller, _$httpBackend_,   $rootScope, menuFactory){
                //  place   here    mocked  dependencies                        
                    $httpBackend =  _$httpBackend_;                     
                    $httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:3000/dishes").respond([
                    {
                  "id": 0,...
},
                  {
                  "id": 1, ..

                  }]);
                    scope   =   $rootScope.$new();
                    MenuController =    $controller('MenuController',   {                       
                    $scope: scope,  menuFactory:    menuFactory });
                    $httpBackend.flush();   
  }));
```

and after injection include tests:

```
it('should have showDetails as false', function () {

    expect(scope.showDetails).toBeFalsy();

  });
```

after this edit just be careful that $httpBackend is expect to GET localhost:3000 but before that if you are using ngRoute it will GET templates so you should handle that issue as well.

Comment: Thank you , but i have tried moving the tests everywhere and still gives errors, can u please update the code and send me a plunker or post it in ur answer?   thanks again.

Comment: When i move the tests to the end i receive this message: scope is not define , that`s because scope is defined inside inject.

Comment: but the scope error may occur because of your factory, does the factory variable return works correctly